# Report Design Editor in VB.Net when program is running

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, vba, crystal-reports

Here is my question.

I have been searching a lot but i dont find any resource or stuff about this and i dunno where to start.

I'm trying to do a Report Designer for end user. Like the one that adds
vb.net when u add     to proyect a .rpt file. But i wanted to do it on
the run, so the end user can change the desing of the report as they
want.

Any one have an idea how to do it? or where i can find resources to read for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to search the Crystal Reports documentation.

Comment: I don't think the one that comes with Visual Studio has a good end-user designer, actually. Sorry about that. All you can do, I think, is stuff like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20670/Dynamic-Crystal-Report-with-C

Comment: i dont have the one who comes with vb.net 2010, i have bought the version 2011 but i dunno where to start

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer, you might want to look into [Microsoft Report Builder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460.aspx) - Microsoft's report authoring environment for business users.